# UpdateNow not set? (Language monitor problems)

Tags: winapi, dll, printing, driver, inf

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a printer language monitor without using WIN32 API's AddMonitor() (i.e. by editing the Registry or using an INF file), but I keep running into problems, and I'm not seeing any good examples of INF files for this purpose.

For testing purposes, I edited ntprint.inf to point PJL_LANGUAGE_MONITOR to my DLL instead of pjlmon.dll, and changed the appropriate Registry keys to also do the same. Every time I try to reload the print spooler I can see that it seems to successfully load my language monitor, based on debug output, but when I print I keep getting debug messages that say "UpdateNow not set" with a PID of whatever editor I'm using.

My question is, do you think this "UpdateNow not set" message is related to the problem, or is it just some inconsequential symptom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Employer moved on to another project, moot point now.